# How do I get NotePad++ Document List Panel to show full pathnames?

Tags: notepad++

I've turned on the Document List Panel (aka Doc Switcher) in Notepad++ but I cannot find a way to get it to show the full pathnames.

Either the feature doesn't exist or my StackOverflowSearchFu and GoogleFu are weak.

Comment: Are you referring to something documented that indicates that showing full pathnames is an available feature? Hovering and being the active doc shows the full path - guessing that is not what you are looking for?

Comment: No, not feature I've found docmented; initially looking to see if I just missed something.  

To your other point, though, when I hover over the file in the Doc Switcher, all I see is the unqualified filename -- no path (I'm on v7.3).  

I have 18 web.config files open; the Doc selector isn't helping me find the one I need.

If I click on each one, that changes the Most-Recently-Used list, which affects the behavior of Ctrl-Tab, so that's undesirable.

In testing this, however, I discovered that Ctrl-Tab pops up a list of fully qualified filenames -- so it's a partial workaround.

Comment: Thanks CTRL+TAB helps me too :)
Maybe this help you (I don't use it) https://github.com/young-developer/nppNavigateTo